# Why does the Graph API profile feed return deleted posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I am having the exact opposite problem that I find in many searches. The graph API result for the [page feed I am grabbing](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=26920394576/feed) is including posts that the page administrator has deleted from display on the page itself (via the standard FB user interface).

I want to display a feed of recent activity on the site, but the client does not want certain content associated with the brand, so they need to be able to police the feed. Is there any way to identify "deleted" wall posts and not display them from the feed results?

Comment: Which one is deleted for example?

Comment: The first post, with "god damn" in it. ;D It does not display on the page (http://www.facebook.com/SkylineChili) but is in the feed. Looks like they also deleted the free coupons one.

Comment: Are you sure the posts are deleted, and that they haven't just marked them as spam or changed the page wall to display posts by the page only?

Comment: I do know that posts by other users are showing on the wall, but I do not know what method they are using to remove them I will find out!

Comment: Unfortunately the answers I'm getting from them are rather inconclusive. Am I correct in understanding that marking something as Spam does not exclude it from the feed?

Comment: @CatherineOBrien-Sandrick Why don't you just make a page yourself to test it out.  Create a post, view it in the graph api, then delete it in different ways and see what happens. Please post your answer when you find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) [`stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) contains wall posts and supports a boolean `is_hidden` column, so you could try a query like

```
select post_id,actor_id,message from stream where source_id=26920394576 and is_hidden=0
```

to see whether it omits the deleted posts.

Running the query now I see 1 post from "Free Coupons" which has been hidden, and another which hasn't - and it's the latter that appears on the Skyline Chili page.

You can execute FQL via the Graph API using `/fql?q=select ...`.

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked. I actually used the FQL to create a "blacklist" and then tested the feed items against the blacklist, but it works! I got into this out of client request, but the FQL stuff is interesting...will have to learn more.